# How do I delete a database from a Visual studio 2015 project

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have all these databases that I don't want, I want to start fresh, when I right click there is no delete option and if I delete them from the solution explorer my program breaks.
[image: These are all my databases...]

Comment: http://imgur.com/QLlm2nC

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways, but one that would surely work is writing a script:

1. Right click on dt_DatabaseDataSet and select *New Query*
2. write,  DROP DATABASE dt_DatabaseDataSet
3. Execute the query, this should do the work

Comment: When I right click it theres no New query option :(

Comment: On the **Command Bar** of the **Data Designer** , there should be a _Query_ command. 

This is where you usually type in your queries.

Comment: I think this is just going to delete the file, it wont even let me do it because it says that the path is invalid. Is there a different way? I tried looking on the internet but i cant find anything.